# Is there any way to pass Account object to the controller class

Tags: controller

I used apex:param but it doesn't pass objects

```
<apex:param value="{!a.Id}" name="AIs" assignTo="{!AId}"/>
```

Comment: <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" name="AIs"  assignTo="{!AId}"/>

Comment: if you define the object in the class and then use it on the page, it will bind automatically.

Comment: This should work. You are missing the `rerender` attribute in your parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Id passed via param and then query the account on the controller. Or else you as Guy mentioned in the  comments you can declare an instance of Account and use this instance on the page, and the updated values will be available on the page.

```
-----Apex-----
public class SampleClass{

Account accountObj{get; set;}

}

------Page----
<apex:inputText value={!accountObj.Name}/>
```